# ¿Cómo agregar elementos detrás de una forward_list?

Tags: c++

Estaba probando la clase `std::forward_list` y para eso quise crear una con
cuatro números, así que intente lo siguiente:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> li;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        li.push_front(i);
    }

    for (auto i : li) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo esperaba que me salga `0 1 2 3` pero me salió invertido,
`3 2 1 0`.  Y claro, porque `push_front` agrega cada numero *al frente* de la
lista y no detrás. Como `forward_list` no tiene `push_back` intente lo siguiente:

```
auto it = li.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    it = li.insert_after(it, i);
}
```

Esta vez el programa crashea con un segmentation fault al ejecutarlo. También di
con el problema: al estar vacia la lista, `li.begin()` devuelve `li.end()` que
apunta a un lugar inexistente e `insert_after` lo desreferencia.

[image]

Y ya me rendí, así que ¿cómo puedo agregar elementos detras de la `forward_list`?

Comment: Amigo, si quieres agregar elementos al final, porque usas un forward list? Si necesitas incertar en ambas posiciones, porque no te sirve un `std::deque`?

Comment: @Pablochaches pensaba que se podía agregar elementos en un solo sentido como si fuera una lista enlazada que guarda un puntero al siguiente nodo. Obviamente podría usar una std::deque o una std::list pero tenía curiosidad de saber si se podía solo con la forward_list.

Comment: Tienes que recorrer toda la lista, desde `begin()` hasta `end()` y quedarte con el último distinto de `end()`. Y ya podrías usar `insert_after()`. Inténtalo y nos cuentas :-)